# search specific set of words in .txt file

Tags: python, string, search, readlines, txt

I have a txt file with the following dataset as list

```
Name:AP_A
Ch:0
Ptx:20
CCA:-68
AvgThroughput:{}
Data packets_sent:{}
Data_packets lost:{}
rts_cts_sent:{}
rts_cts_lost:{}
in-degA:0.0006766529737718963
out-degA:1.1814245426625214
-----------------
Name:AP_B
Ch:0
Ptx:5
CCA:-90
AvgThroughput:{}
Data packets_sent:{}
Data_packets lost:{}
rts_cts_sent:{}
rts_cts_lost:{}
in-degB:1.6025829114087657
out-degB:0.0006766529737718963
```

I need to search for these lines / words and have them as the next data set

```
---AP_A data---
Name:AP_A
in-degA:0.0006766529737718963
out-degA:1.1814245426625214
---AP_B data---
Name:AP_B
in-degB:1.6025829114087657
out-degB:0.0006766529737718963
```

i have a code to make this , but i cant make that i describe

```
archivo_ficha= "ficha_nodos_triang28.txt"
with open(archivo_ficha,'r') as inputfile:
     lines = []
     for line in inputfile:
         lines.append(line)

         search_words1=['Name:AP_A','in-degA','out-degA','Name:AP_B','in-degB','out-degB']
         for line in inputfile:
             if any(word in line  for word in search_words1):
                print("---datos_NodoA---")
                print(line)

                print("---datos_NodoB---")
                print(line)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking just to print the data?  You could do that with grep: `grep -E '^(Name|(in|out)-deg[AB]):' filename` and be **almost** exactly what you asked.

Comment: Well yes, I need to have it on the console screen, but also have it as a variable to later work with that data, thanks for your contribution mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that you have data A and data B. You know that you get either a string with "AP_X" or "degX" from the lines you are interested in. Plus you want to print a flag to say which data you enter in.

Well, your data start with "Name:AP_X".

You set all "write" var for A and B to false. When you first meet "Name:AP_A", you turn write_A on, keep write_B off, print your header which will no be printed twice (cause only when write_A = False and "Name:AP_A" in line) and then you write the lines containing the labels of interest.

```
archivo_ficha= "ficha_nodos_triang28.txt"

with open(archivo_ficha,'r') as inputfile:

     write_A = False; write_B = False; out_list = []

     for line in inputfile:

         if 'AP_A' in line and write_A == False:
            out_list.append("---datos_NodoA---"); print (out_list[-1])
            write_A = True; write_B = False

         if write_A == True and 'AP_A' in line or 'degA' in line:
            out_list.append(line.strip()); print (out_list[-1])


         if 'AP_B' in line and write_B == False:
            out_list.append("---datos_NodoA---"); print (out_list[-1])
            write_B = True; write_A = False

         if write_B == True and 'AP_B' in line or 'degB' in line:
             out_list.append(line.strip()); print (out_list[-1])

     inputfile.close()
```

Output:

```
---datos_NodoA---
Name:AP_A
in-degA:0.0006766529737718963
out-degA:1.1814245426625214
---datos_NodoB---
Name:AP_B
in-degB:1.6025829114087657
out-degB:0.0006766529737718963
```

Answer (score 1):

As [PaulProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1168588/paulprogrammer) suggested, you can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html). In Python:

```
import re
archivo_ficha = "ficha_nodos_triang28.txt"
matches = [re.search(r"(Name|(in|out))(.+)", line) for line in open(archivo_ficha, 'r')]
matches = [m.group() for m in matches if m]
```

`matches` is a list from which you can extract the necessary data:

```
['Name:AP_A',
 'in-degA:0.0006766529737718963',
 'out-degA:1.1814245426625214',
 'Name:AP_B',
 'in-degB:1.6025829114087657',
 'out-degB:0.0006766529737718963']
```

These could then be split into groups of 3 and produce the output you desire.

### Explanation:

`re.search` scans through a string looking for substring that matches the pattern.
Here the pattern is `(Name|(in|out))(.+)`.

- The first part `Name|(in|out)` means:

  1. Find `Name`
  2. if not found, find `in` or `out`
  3. if a match is found, the execution is continued. Otherwise, the search moves onto the next line.
- The second part `(.+)` consists of special characters to match the rest of the string:

  - `.` matches any character (except a newline)
  - `+` matches the previous character (`.`) 1 or more times

Comment: Thanks or share this mate, and I appreciate your solution to this problem